# Access Windows shared network files from Android app

Tags: java, android, file-access, jcifs

I'm trying to access a shared file from my app, e.g `//172.24.9.13/c/2012xp.mdb`

By doing:

```
new File("//172.24.9.13/c/2012xp.mdb");
```

it doesn't work.

I found the jCIFS library, and creating

```
new SmbFile("//172.24.9.13/c/2012xp.mdb");
```

it works, but the problem is that I need a `java.io.File`.

I have also seen that there is no way to mount smb's on android devices without rooting them.

Is there a way to get a `java.io.File` instance of my shared file?

Comment: what are you trying to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll be able to read it as `java.io.File` because it's not one.

If you absolutely need a `java.io.File` you'll probably have to call `smbFile.getInputStream()` and copy to a local file, than you use that local file.

Considering it's a `.mdb` file you're probably wanting to read data from the DataBase, and it might be a huge file and you don't want to copy it over. On that situation, your only option is to setup a server, with an api that replies in JSON and your app will send GET requests to it.

Answer (score 0):

try this code. i'm not sure about .mdb file format. but this works for PDF files.

first create a  SmbFileInputStream using your smb file.

```
in = new SmbFileInputStream(sFile);
```

Then create a output file in the device storage (SD card)

```
outputfile = new File(dir, "todevice.pdf");
```

Then create a FileOutputStream (java IO)

```
out = new FileOutputStream(outputfile);
```

Then read input(SMB) and write it in to the output(IO)

```
while ((read = in.read(buffer)) > 0  ) 
{
    try {
           out.write(buffer, 0, read);
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
}
```

Now u have a file on your sd card